# I'm trying to make an API in python that receives data in JSON

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make an API which depending on which store the user likes and what specific item they like it will retrieve the data in JSON, for example, in Tesco search for Nutella, it works perfectly to find when I do it for just 1 store but when I did it for more than 1 it get errors.

I've tried a for loop and if loop, I've gotten better results
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup libraries to do this.

**My code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

num = int(input('''press 1 for tesco
press 2 for morrisions
press 3 for sainsbury's
'''))

print("please enter the food you want to search for: ")
flag = num%2
txt = input("")

if flag == 1:
    tesco_url = requests.get('https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/search?query=' + txt).text
elif flag == 2:
    morrisons_url = requests.get('https://groceries.morrisons.com/search?entry=' + txt).text
elif flag == 3:
    sainsburys_url = requests.get('https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplayView?catalogId=10123&langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=OYaxfyCjgnRApUa%2FS%2BjRmgHslGfDEUtd3xECMndoz2f9gvq5KRuP8TuhW4m1jnUT%2FJU3fBivUiAIozuhmBLJJJQe6gcTedPJTASuwsZfLkt49e%2FYAPxDyWxCjeiyFxNN5WjSEdcW7LMdmfJbn3TmGVBZKVIxqu1zUw7IT8Qo2afgUyuCpJPcxPbmc2gWJMpi#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10123&categoryId=&parent_category_rn=&top_category=&pageSize=60&orderBy=RELEVANCE&searchTerm=' + txt).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(flag, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "My API.py", line 23, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(flag, 'lxml')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 245, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: You are passing `1` to BeatufulSoup and is expecting an html text!?

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup requires XML, which you probably forgot to update when adding more stores. Also I'm not sure why you have `flag = num%2`, as flag will then only be values [0, 1]. If you replace `flag` with `num`, it should work as expected.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

num = int(input('''press 1 for tesco
press 2 for morrisions
press 3 for sainsbury's
'''))

print("please enter the food you want to search for: ")
flag = num                   # <--- notice this
txt = input("")

if flag == 1:
    markup = requests.get('https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/search?query=' + txt).text
elif flag == 2:
    markup = requests.get('https://groceries.morrisons.com/search?entry=' + txt).text
elif flag == 3:
    markup = requests.get('https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplayView?catalogId=10123&langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=OYaxfyCjgnRApUa%2FS%2BjRmgHslGfDEUtd3xECMndoz2f9gvq5KRuP8TuhW4m1jnUT%2FJU3fBivUiAIozuhmBLJJJQe6gcTedPJTASuwsZfLkt49e%2FYAPxDyWxCjeiyFxNN5WjSEdcW7LMdmfJbn3TmGVBZKVIxqu1zUw7IT8Qo2afgUyuCpJPcxPbmc2gWJMpi#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10123&categoryId=&parent_category_rn=&top_category=&pageSize=60&orderBy=RELEVANCE&searchTerm=' + txt).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I've tried that and i get the same error ive taken the flag out completely but still get the same error

Comment: You get the error if you pass an integer. Try running my code, it works on my machine.